# How can I convert this object containing an array of JSONObjects to a JSONArray so that I can call get(i) on the array using java?

Tags: java, json

The library I am using is JSON.simple.

I am parsing a response from a query which succesfully returns an object containing an array of JSONObjects.  I am now trying to convert it to a JSONArray so that I can return each JSONObject.

queryResult is a String.

```
   Object obj = JSONValue.parse(queryResult);
```

The debugger shows that the JSONObjects are in this object as shown below.

- "obj" = JSONArray (id = ...)

  - array = Object[121] (id = ...)

    - [0...99]

      - [0] = JSONObject (id = ...)
      - [1] = JSONObject (id = ...)
      - [2] = JSONObject (id = ...)
      - [3] = JSONObject (id = ...)
      - [4] = JSONObject (id = ...)
        ......

When I try to cast it to JSONArray it throws an ClassCastException.

```
   JSONArray array = (JSONArray) obj;
```

So, how can I convert this object being recognized as a JSONArray containing an array of JSONObjects to a JSONArray so that I can call get(i) on the array using java?

Thank you.

Comment: You should be able to cast to `JSONArray`. However, make sure you're casting to (and/or importing) the correct `JSONArray`. The version in the simple library versus the non-simple one is totally different.

Comment: Thank you for commenting so quickly.  I do not exactly understand what you are saying.  What do you mean the version is different and if so how do I deal with that?

Comment: This fixed it.  Thank you very much for giving me that idea.

Comment: org.json.simple.JSONArray array = (org.json.simple.JSONArray) obj;

Comment: Now try `import org.json.simple.JSONArray;` and see what breaks. :-)

Comment: Ha nice. Thank you once again.

Comment: @George - you should post it as an answer to be accepted before someone else tried to steal credit ;)